# Total price based shipping extension not working opencart v2.x

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart2.x

I am using the following extension to calculate shipping charge based on total price. Extension is installed and enabled too. But its not working in checkout.
How to solve this? I am using Fastor theme and opencart version is 2.x.
Kindly help.

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17494]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Hello @JoséLuis Thanks for the suggestion. I have only installed the extension. I have not written any code. Its supposed to work after i just install the extension in opencart. So i do not have any code to post.

Comment: Maybe you could precise the ranges you use for configuring the extension? A error in these settings can be a possible cause.